# I just wanna disable my secure boot policy on win 8 to install ubuntu,how do i do that?

Tags: windows-8

i tried googlinmg my problem,but couldn't quite find a solution for that.I've got HP pavilion e0539TX Pearl white and i won't get a secure boot manager in the UEFI option after restarting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable secure boot and enable legacy boot.

Shut down your computer and reboot. Hold the F10 key as it restarts and you should go into the setup menus. Select the 'security menu' then 'secure boot configuration', then after clicking a 'accept' screen you should be able to change your settings.